# Why Kotlin doesn't have explicit typing?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, type-inference

I am curious about this, why would kotlin designers think this would be a good idea to drop explicit typing in Kotlin ?

To me, explicit typing is not a "pain" to write in Java (or any other strongly typed language) : all IDE can assist me to automaticaly type my variable.

It adds great understanding of the code (that's why I don't like weakly-typed languages, I have no idea what kind of variables I'm dealing with).

Also, and this is my main issue with that, it makes the code more bug-prone.

Example :
Java : Easily identified as a String, all good

```
String myPrice = someRepository.getPrice(); // Returns a String
myTextView.setText(myPrice);
```

Java : Easily identified as an int, code smell with `setText()`

```
int myPrice = someRepository.getPrice(); // Returns an int, code smell !!
myTextView.setText(String.valueOf(myPrice)); // Problem avoided
```

Kotlin : ????

```
val myPrice = someRepository.getPrice(); // What does it return ?
myTextView.setText(myPrice); // Possible hidden bug with setText(@StringRes int) instead of setText(String) !!
```

No explicit typing in Kotlin is the biggest drawback in Kotlin imo. I try to understand this design choice.

I'm not really looking for "patches" to fix the example / avoid the presented code smell, I try to understand the main reason behind the removal of explicit typing. It has to be more than "less typing / easier to read". It only removes a couple of characters (one still have to write `val` / `var`), and explicit typing in Kotlin adds some caracters anyway...

Static typing without explicit typing is, to me, the worst case scenario to deal with hidden bugs / spaghetti bugs : if one class (let's say "Repository") changes it return type (from `String` to `int` for example). With explicit typing, compilation would fail at the class calling "Repository". Without explicit typing, compilation may not fail and the wrong type of variable may "travel" through classes and change the behavior of the classes because of its type. This is dangerous and undetected.

The fix is easy ; explicitly type the variable. But this is Kotlin we're speaking, a language made for code golfers : people won't explicitely type their variables, as it takes even more time to do so in kotlin than turtle-java. Yikes!

Comment: If if bothers you that much, you can still explicitly type in Kotlin as you please.

Comment: You can write like this:
val myValue: String = someRepository.getValue()

Comment: Well actually it isn't Kotlins fault that someone thought `getValue` is a useful method name. Kotlin does this (and Java added similar support) because you mostly don't need the type additionally to how you initialize your variable. When the way you initialize a variable isn't clear or ambiguous, then work on that first, since that can be on other places as well. And if that isn't suitable, use the explicit type like @fjc and @AlexShevelev suggested: `val myValue: String = ....`.

Comment: @Tom My problem with the "optional explicit typing" is : people won't do it.

Comment: If it is really bad for you, you can turn on variable types prompt in your IDE. If not, change IDE.

Comment: There is an IDE feature that may help you: the type hints. Ctrl/Cmd + Shift + A → Appearance: Show parameter name hints. This will also show a type hint for every local variable that has no explicit type.

Comment: If you're not sure about what you're working with, then you need better method / variable naming conventions.

Comment: oh, the Stockholm Syndrome of Java developers. Almost every other statically typed language has had this feature for years, even the dinosaur of C++.

Comment: @GhostCat While I really appreciated your answer, there's no real "argument" or "reason" explaining this deliberate choice in your answer. I still don't know why Kotlin permit non explicit typing except that "c++ has it so Kotlin should have it". 

Some much effort has been put on Kotlin design to remove any ambiguous code (null safety, when safety with enum, etc), it sounds ludicrous to me they'd allow ambiguous typing (doesn't matter static typing or not, at the end of the day, even if the compiler knows what's going on, it's developpers that are writing code).

Comment: @NinoLenoska if you need types in your code to understand it 9/10 times it means that you name things wrong. In you question "getPrice(); // What does it return ?" it returns a price, that all we need to know. That method shouldn't return int or string, that's is the problem here. If you want string representation of a price you should call ToString() or something similar.

Comment: @abc667 You don't understand. In Android, TextView.setText(String) is completely different that TextView.setText(int). In java, this is easily avoided because no matter what, you have to declare your type. In kotlin, it's optional and people want to code golf with it, so they won't do it.

Comment: @NinoLenoska did you read my comment? setText() is not the problem here. getPrice() should return price object and you should call myTextView.setText(myPrice.toString()); or something similar like toStringRepresentation()

Comment: @abc667 I would personally say the bigger problem is that Android uses these integers that mean something in a myTextView.setText(...) method. It seems like they should have gone with a plain enum here and did the conversion during android compilation

Answer (score 17):

First of all: Kotlin has **static** typing. The compiler knows exactly which type goes or comes where. And you are always free to write that down, like

```
fun sum(a: Int, b: Int): Int {
  val c: Int = 1
```

The point is: you can write a lot of code that simply *relies* on the fact that anything you do is statically typed, and type checked, too!

Do you really need to know whether you are adding two doubles or two ints or two longs, when all you "care" to look at is `a + b`?

In the end, this is about balancing different requirements. Leaving out the type *can* be helpful: less code that needs to be read and understood by human readers.

Of course: if you write code so that people *constantly* turn to their IDE for the IDE to tell them the actual, inferred type of something, then you turned a helpful feature into a problem!

The real answer here is: it depends. I have been in many code reviews where C++ people discussed the use of the `auto` keyword. There were a lot of situations, where using `auto` did make the code much easier to read and understand, because you could focus on "what happens with the variable", instead of looking 1 minute at its declaration, trying to understand its type. But there were also occasional examples where `auto` achieved the exact opposite, and a "fully typed" declaration was easier to follow.

And given the comment by the OP: you should know what you are doing in the first place. Meaning: when you write code, you don't just invoke "any" method that you find on some object. You call a method because you have to. You better *know* what it does, and what it returns to you. I agree, when someone is in a rush, you quickly var-assign and then pass that thing along, that *might* lead to errors. But for each situation where `var` helps with creating a bug, there might be 10 incidents where it helps writing easier to read code. As said: life is about balancing.

Finally: languages shouldn't add features for no reason. And the Kotlin people are carefully balancing features they add. They didn't add type inference because C++ has it. They added it because they carefully researched other languages and found it to be useful to be part of the language. **Any** language feature can be misused. It is **always** up to the programmer to write code that is easy to read and understand. And when your methods have *unclear* signatures, so "reading" their names alone doesn't tell you what is gong on, then blame that on the method name, not on type inference!

Comment: How could someone focus on "what happens with the variable" when they doesn't even know what type it is, and thus, how could they interact correctly with it ?

Comment: @NinoLenoska the compiler knows, the IDE knows, auto complete works in most of them.

Answer (score 7):

To quote Java's [Local-Variable Type Inference JEP](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/286):

> In a call chain like:
>
> ```
> int maxWeight = blocks.stream()
>                     .filter(b -> b.getColor() == BLUE)
>                     .mapToInt(Block::getWeight)
>                     .max();
> ```
>
> no one is bothered (or even notices) that the intermediate types `Stream<Block>` and `IntStream`, as well as the type of the lambda formal `b`, do not appear explicitly in the source code.

Are you bothered about it?

> if one class (let's say "Repository") changes it return type (from String to int for example). With explicit typing, compilation would fail at the class calling "Repository".

If you have overloads like `setText` in your example, then

```
Repository repository = ...;
myTextView.setText(repository.getFormerlyStringNowInt());
```

won't fail without type inference either. To make it fail, your code standard has to require *every* operation's result to be assigned to a local variable, as in

```
Stream<Block> stream1 = blocks.stream();
Predicate<Block> pred = b -> { 
    Color c = b.getColor();
    return c == BLUE;
};
Stream<Block> stream2 = stream1.filter(pred);
ToIntFunction<Block> getWeight = Block::getWeight;
IntStream stream3 = stream2.mapToInt(getWeight);
int maxWeight = stream3.max();
```

And at this point you make bugs easier just from decreased readability and the chance to accidentally use the wrong variable.

Finally, Kotlin wasn't created in a vacuum: the designers could see that when C# introduced local type inference in 2007, it didn't lead to significant problems. Or they could look at Scala, which had it since the beginning in 2004; it had (and has) plenty of user complaints, but local type inference isn't one of them.

Comment: Some great examples, too!

Comment: Chain calls is a completely different topic

Comment: @NinoLenoska The point is that they can produce _exactly_ the same problems local type inference does. So if they are acceptable, it should be acceptable as well. In your example the problem is not caused by local type inference, but by the badly designed `setText` overloads.